# How can I put a button to be always in the center and bottom of my App?

Tags: android, python, android-layout, kivy

I'd like to put an 'Update Button' in the center and bottom of my app, but I also need to add some widgets in the screen.
I put a BoxLayout to be always in the center and bottom of my app, but I need to put a Button inside it and it has to be always in the BoxLayout center bottom too.
[What I did:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZV3f.jpg)

My .kv source code:

```
<WindowMain>:
orientation: 'horizontal'

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: .1, .1
    pos_hint: {"x":1., "bottom":1.}
    padding: 2

    Button:
        size_hint: .2, 1.
        pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'y': 1.}            
        font_name: 'consola'
        text: 'Update'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two empty Labels left and right of the button and space it with the `size_hint` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'FloatLayout' for positioning of the widgets in contrast to the main window.

in py:

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class MainWindow(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

in kv:

```
<WindowMain>:
    Button:
        size_hint: .2, .1
        pos_hint: {'x': .4, 'y': 0}            
        font_name: 'consola'
        text: 'Update'
```

This should have the button start at 40% in and end at 60% being 10% high up. You can then add other widgets anywhere you like in the FloatLayout.